# The :focus pseudo-class and when it is applied

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, focus

The `:focus` selector is used to style elements that have focus in the general sense. But when exactly is it applied, considering cases like mouse down or touch? And how as a web developer can I control it to be consistent?

e.g. here on Stack Overflow, if I mouse down on one of the links, but do not activate, by moving the mouse off before releasing, the link gets keyboard focus (as seen by then pressing tab, the focus goes to the next link). However it does not get the `:focus` style even though it has focus. If I tab onto a link though, I get the `:focus` outline style.

But on one of the websites I am working on, the mouse down gives me the `:focus` style straight away, so there must be some subtle detail.

In this snippet, the `<a>` and `<button>` elements in Chrome for me work like my former description, and the clickable `<div>` seems to work like the latter. But on one of my sites the latter is happening in all 3 cases, and I am not even sure why they are not all the same in this snippet, since I have no extra styles or JS here.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {});
$('.fake-btn').on('click', function() {});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <a href="www.example.com">A link</a>
</p>
<p>
  <button>A button</button>
</p>
<p>
  <div class="fake-btn" tabindex="0">A clickable element</div>
</p>
```

[image: Recording of snippet]

In IE11 Everything works like the default `<a>` and `<button`> in the GIF, including on my other sites. Maybe this is a Chrome bug, or is there still some subtle bit of the spec I missed about when a `:focus` style gets applied? Does the order of pseudo-class CSS rules matter here in some non-obvious way?

Comment: Are you sure you're differentiating between `:focus` and `:active`?

Comment: `:focus` not related necessarily to the mouse. `:focus` firing even if you click on `tab` in your keyboard until you get the element (`button`, `a` etc.) without the mouse. My question is what is your problem exactly? What is the actual result (describe the UI with words - for example, the button should has a `border`) and what is the expected?

Comment: Yes, active has different styles to focus (infact, by default `<div>` seems to have no active style, but there is a `:focus` rule for all elements). What part of the description is not clear, clicking with the mouse sometimes gives the focus style and sometimes not in the different ways I described, but it always gives keyboard focus? e.g. why in the snippet is `<div>` and `<a>` different?

Comment: @Paulie_D I get some degree of "odd" behavior as described even with default browser styles, e.g. in the snippet. :active works as expected during both a keyboard activation, or mouse click, but :focus only displays sometimes, even though the element definitely has keyboard focus

Comment: I found something to make a quick recording of the case in the snippet, hope that is clearer. And on some other sites I have the `<a>` and `<button>` behave exactly like the `<div>` is here (focus style applied on mousedown), but I see nothing that should make this so (e.g. some JS calling `focus()` in a `mousedown` event handler)

Comment: Can you show your site?

Comment: Well the `<div>` is still different for some reason. Managed to reproduced the `<button>` as well, see https://jsfiddle.net/cvc2233y/1/

Comment: Is this still a problem? Adding `*:focus {outline: 5px solid red;}` makes the focus visible. And its working in Chrome and Internet Explorer for me.
See: https://jsfiddle.net/cvc2233y/3/

Comment: After some playing around several times with that, think the key change in your fiddle is the outline is `solid` instead of `auto`? Is a `<button>` or `<a>` with a `outline: size auto colour` special? I looked around but found nothing saying as such. But doing something like `:focus { outline: 5px auto red; border: 1px solid blue; }` just creates more wierdness. e.g. `<a>` gets the blue border but *not* the red outline on mousedown. `<button>` gets both...

Answer (score 3):

`:focus` is the psuedo selector that relates to which field is currently selected by the keyboard. Tabbing through inputs should apply :focus to that input.

`:active` is the pseudo selector that relates to "activating" a button or link. So clicking or touching it will apply `:active` to that element.

In CSS...

```
button:active {
    border: solid red 1px;
}
```

This will add a border of 1px that is red while you take action on that element making it the active link being clicked.

```
button:focus {
    border: solid red 1px;
}
```

This will do the same styling when you tab into that button. For `:focus` to work in some cases the `tabindex` is important. For the same `:focus` styling to work on buttons make sure to include a `tabindex` on them.

If you need more help, let me know.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question? And yes tabindex is needed because most elements are not focus-able at all by default, such as the div in my example, and if you cant focus it you don`t get :focus (including parent elements). But why is :focus only sometimes applied (and differently on different browsers) in response to mousedown, and how to make it consistent (the UI designer preference being to never use :focus for a mouse/touch event)? Why do the things in my example work differently?

Comment: To further answer, buttons should have `:focus` by default. The reason yours doesn't is that you've nested a button inside of an element (the `<p>`) that does not have `:focus` by default.

Most often the CSS files will style buttons so it's good to give them an explicit `:focus` styling just to make sure.

My personally, I always use `:active` for buttons when I want to style the active click state.

Make sure your CSS isn't overriding the `:focus' style on buttons too. Can you post your CSS so I can take a look?

Comment: There is the fiddle/example in the question, it happens even with the default styles.

Comment: Also you don't need active with focus. As an element will be focused before it is active.

Comment: Thats awesome. And even for div's if we want to focus into it, tabindex should include to your div.